# Папка с версткой для Nexus 7 (800x1280 214dpi)

Tags: android, android-layout, design

Имеется макет приложения 720х1280. Я создал три папки: sw600dp - для  720х1280 160dpi и перенес размеры с макета в соотношении 1:1, поле чего   создал папку sw480dp - для  720х1280 240dpi и перенес размеры с макета в соотношении 1:1.5  и так же папку sw360dp - для  720х1280 320dpi и размеры соответственно 1:2. Запустил на эмуляторе в этих  трех вариациях - вроде все работает нормально. Дальше стоит задача сделать тоже самое для 7" и 10" планшетов. Первое с чем я столкнулся, что минимальная сторона для  Nexus 7 равна примерно 600dp и он берет ресурсы с папки sw600dp, но ресурсы из этой папки ему не очень подходят и верстка на нем смотриться немого криво. У меня вопрос, что  делать (какую папку нужно создавать) для него и в каком соотношении переносить рамеры с макета (макет имеется) ???

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Похоже вы так ничего и не поняли в верстке под разные экраны. Все вообще не так делается. Макет этот оставьте в покое - не надо его увеличивать и уменьшать. Не надо столько активити под каждый типоразмер. Их требуется всего две: одна под все смарты и одна под планшеты. Разбирайтесь с этим вопросом, изучайте верстку готовых приложений (на гитхабе их тысячи). НЕ ПИШИТЕ больше ничего, пока не поймете, пожалейте свое напрасно потраченное время

Comment: @pavlofff Ну как же так? Как мне тогда сделать адекватное отображение виджетов на разных  экранах, как мне проставить их размеры в единичном экземпляре, если они потом на разных экранах по разному смотряться?

Comment: @pavlofff или вы о том что много папок  и надо было сделать для смартфонов только одно sw360dp и добавить отдельной файлы dimens и добавить различные размеры там? Это пока что тестовый вариант..для наглядности!

Comment: @pavlofff будьте добры, поясните мне пожалуйста, если смартфон с разрешением 720х1280 160dpi  имеет минимальную ширину 600 и Nexus 7 имеет примерно такую же ширину, то они будут брать одни и те же ресурсы, а должны брать разные, как этого избежать?

Comment: Какой физический размер экрана у "смартфона" с параметрами 720х1280 160dpi - 10 дюймов?

Comment: @pavlofff диагональ 4.8"

Comment: Ну вы возьмите калькулятор и посчитайте. Теорему Пифагора знаете? сколько дюймов в DP выше писал уже. Можете просто головой подумать: если Nexus 7 имеет диагональ 7" уже при 214dp, то при 160dp с таким же разрешением - точно, блин - 4.8" :(

Comment: Вот есть отличное приложение от Google - [iosched](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.samples.apps.iosched), которое создано компанией специально для того, чтобы продемонстрировать лучшие практики в написании android-приложений, особенно компания акцентирует внимание на демонстрации правильных практик по поддержке экранов всех форм и размеров. Изучайте [исходники этого приложения](https://github.com/google/iosched/tree/master/android) до полного просветления по верстке. В любых непонятных ситуациях думайте о том, что именно так делают профессионалы и разбирайтесь - почему